# Does BES cause "last logged" event in ESM?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, bes

I apologize if this is a bit of a newbie question, but I'm noticing a few of my members have "Last Logged By" as the administrator account in my ESM (Exchange 2003). I'm running BES 4.1 (which I did not set up - I just maintain) and the BES services are using the admin account (I know this is not best practice, however once again I did not set this up).

All of the users experiencing this in the ESM have BB's on our BES and this event seems to happen when they've been away from the office for at least a few hours. I myself have a company BB but I've been unable to replicate this with my account.

While I feel as though it's my BES logging these events, I just want to be sure to ensure that there's no compromise on our system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because it is accessing the mailbox in some capacity. Best practice is to have a non-admin account, called BESAdmin. This user is not an admin, but has Exchange read-only access to the mailboxes.

EDIT: I'm actually surprised it works. Is this current account a domain admin?

Comment: Thanks Dan. That's what I figured but it's nice to know my suspicions are correct. I've read that BES is supposed to be installed with a BESadmin account, but I can find no trace of a BESadmin account in ADUC.